# Best way to get MS-SQL Connection with Python-Skrip from Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Server, with the following package installed to get Python on this machine:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Now I need to connect to a "Microsoft SQL-Server 2012".

I read something about `pyodbc` and `pymssql`, but I have no idea which one is better. Also I am wondering if there is an Ubuntu package which can be installed, or if I have to download and compile the module by my own (which I haven't done before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tutorial that worked for me:
http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/

I had only one little problem because of a missing c++ compiler. So i had to install this package befor following the tutorial:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```